# MATLAB MEX-file builds successfully but nothing is displayed

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, mex

I am new here so I will try to expose my issue clearly:
I am currently developping a program in MATLAB language that has to load a library to work properly. However, the latter is written in C/C++ (I cannot access to it) but I can call it in C++ and then create a MEX-file to use returned values.
Using Visual Studio 2012, I sucessfully managed to call the library (the portRead function returns me a value when I give it parameters-values as arguments). Here is my code:

```
// Test704.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#define _AFXDLL
#define _tprintf mexPrintf
//#include "afx.h"
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "704IO.h"
#include "Test704.h"
//#include "mat.h"
#include "mex.h"
//mxArray *matGetNextVariable(MATFile *mfp, const char **name);
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CWinApp theApp;  // The one and only application object

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using namespace std;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[], TCHAR *envp[])
//void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

//int     nRetCode(0);
HMODULE hModule(::GetModuleHandle(NULL));
short   valueRead;

  if (hModule != NULL)
  {
    // Initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
      //_tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
      //mexPrintf("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed");
      //nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      while(true)
      {
        valueRead = PortRead(1, 780, -1);
        _tprintf(_T("Value Read = %i\n"), valueRead);
        //mexPrintf("Value Read = %i",valueRead);
        Sleep(1000);  // Sleep for 1s so we can see the value on the screen
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
    //mexPrintf("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed");
   // nRetCode = 1;
  }

  //return nRetCode;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int _tmain();
    //short   valueRead;
    //valueRead = PortRead(1, 780, -1);
    //_tprintf(_T("Value Read = %i\n"), valueRead);
    //mexPrintf("Value Read = %i",valueRead);
    return;
}
```

You can see that I commented my unsuccessful researches to solve my issue...
This code returns me "valueRead = 255" in a console, which means the program is working well. What I want now is to retrieve this value in MATLAB. You may also notice that I created a mexFunction; indeed, I read into documentation that a gateway to MATLAB (=the mexFunction) has to be created in C++.

Now, using MATLAB R2015a, I created the following MEX-file:

```
function test()    
location = 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\MATLAB\';
mylib = [location '704IO.lib'];
mex( 'Test704.cpp', mylib)
```

And instead of retrieving "valueRead", I just have a message that indicates

```
>Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'. MEX completed successfully
```

So, as a summary, I have functionnal C++ code but I cannot figure out why I am unable to link it to MATLAB in order to use it! I have been seeking for the solution for days, and I think it is time for me to ask for help :)

Thanks a lot for your help!
(P.-S.: I a beginner in C++, so sorry for misunderstanding/bad syntax )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling

```
mex( 'Test704.cpp', mylib)
```

you only *compile* the `.cpp` file. As a result, MATLAB tells you that `MEX completed successfully`, that means the compilation worked. As a result you will see a new file in the working directory: Depending on your OS, it might be called e.g. `Test704.mexw64` (Windows, 64-bit), or a similar name. You need to call `mex` everytime you changed something in the C++ code, so the file is re-compiled.

This compiled file/function can now be used like a normal MATLAB-function. To call it without any additional parameters, simply type

```
Test704()
```

in MATLAB. That way, the `mexFunction()` is executed, and that way your `_tmain()` will run.

*Note:* your C++ code will write e.g.`valueRead = 255` to the MATLAB command window, but it will *not* create a variable called `valueRead` in MATLAB. To create such a variable, you would have to return the read value from `_tmain` to the `mexFunction`, and allocate a MATLAB variable there.

**Edit:**
You have a bug in the `mexFunction`: there you write:

```
int _tmain();
```

which is *not* a function call, but a function *declaration*. You tell `C++` that you have a function called `_tmain()`, but it is never called. What you need is a function call, i.e. only `_tmain()` without the `int`. Remember that you need to supply the parameters `int argc, TCHAR *argv[], TCHAR *envp[]`. I simply set these to zero here:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    _tmain(0,0,0);
    return;
}
```

Comment: @ManaV I found a bug in your `mexFunction`. See the edited answer - now it should work I guess.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I remember to have a warning message about this at some point too. So now, when I compile
 'function test() 
Test704()' 
MATLAB still not does displays anything but it is "Busy" for a very long time.. we're not so far from success :) Could it be because of what you wrote in your Note?

Comment: Does it work with `mexPrintf`? If not, you could try to add `mexPrintf('Test\n')` at different places in the code (e.g. start of `_tmain()`) to find out what the program really does, and what executed and what not. You could also try debugging using Visual Studio. The *Note* should not have influence on the output to the Matlab console.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to put mexPrintf() in both _tmain() and mexFunction() but I always got the following error message : "Test704.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mexPrintf referenced in the function _wmain (*if the mexPrintf() is in _tmain*)/_mexFunction (*if the mexPrintf() is in mexFunction*)"

Comment: Strange. Make sure you do not have a `_` before `mexPrintf`. Does that work?

Comment: No it is not, unfortunaly. But on top of my code I have already written "#define _tprintf mexPrintf" and it is not a problem.

Comment: So I'm afraid I cannot do anything else for you, sorry! Please try debugging the code using Visual Studio, as described in the [MATLAB documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html). Step through the entire function to see what exactly happens. That way you will find out, what functions exactly are called, and thus why nothing is printed to the MATLAB console. (Or maybe somebody else sees a bug in the code or can help you further...)

Comment: I have launched the "test()" function 20min ago and forgot about it... and it worked! It appears that you solved my issue, but that my program just takes a long time to run. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh perfect :) I'm always glad to help

Comment: Sorry to recall you but how do you " return the read value from _tmain to the mexFunction, and allocate a MATLAB variable there. " please? I am searching but I still do not understand that..

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943953/how-to-return-a-float-value-from-a-mex-function-and-how-to-retrieve-it-from-m-f) help? If no, can you please ask a separate question on how to return values from a C++ MEX file to MATLAB? You can also insert a link to this question so one has more context.

Comment: Not really, so I have asked the separated question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783441/return-values-from-a-c-mex-file-to-matlab