# Return values from a C++ MEX file to MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am coding a MATLAB program that retrieves data from C++ code. To do so, I have created a MEX-file in MATLAB and a gateway mexFunction.
Although the read value can be read in MATLAB, I cannot retrieve it to work with it. If this is unclear, I have quite the same problem as here ([How to return a float value from a mex function, and how to retrieve it from m-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943953/how-to-return-a-float-value-from-a-mex-function-and-how-to-retrieve-it-from-m-f)) but I want to retrieve a value displayed by my C++ program.
Here is my C++ code:

```
#define _AFXDLL
#define  _tprintf mexPrintf
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "704IO.h"
#include "Test704.h"
#include "mex.h"
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CWinApp theApp;  // The one and only application object

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using namespace std;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[], TCHAR *envp[])
//void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
HMODULE hModule(::GetModuleHandle(NULL));
short   valueRead;

  if (hModule != NULL)
  {
    // Initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
      //mexPrintf("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed");
      //nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        valueRead = PortRead(1, 780, -1);
        mexPrintf("Value Read = %i\n",valueRead);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
  }
  //return nRetCode;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    _tmain(0,0,0);
    return;
}
```

Please tell me if you need any further information about my issue?

Comment: In the link you posted the answer is very good, as good as it can get. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: It is indeed very good, but inapropriate for me: I want to retrieve the value from _intmain() which is supposed to read a device's output and changes. In the solution given in the link I posted, the value is given "hardly" in the code and I do not want that.

Comment: What do you meant hardly? Its just a number, you can do the same. Instead of `data[0] = 1;` , do `data[0]=_tmain(0,0,0)` (or whatever other value you want to return).

Comment: To me hardly means that the value is contained in the code.
I have already tried `data[0]=_tmain(0,0,0)` but it simply returns me the value 0 while the returned value of Test704() is 1.

Comment: Then show us the code! You need to show all the code, else we cant help you! There is no `Test704() ` in the code you showed, nor you tried to return any value!

Comment: I am pertty sure that code is not in my `C:\Users\admin\Documents\MATLAB\` .

Comment: My mistake, I have forgotten to tell you that Test704() is the name of my C++ file. Here is my MEX code and you will find in my question my C++ code: `function test() mexValue = Test704()`

Comment: If my answer does not satisfy you, please, edit your question to include full code of what have you tried and what returns always 0 instead if posting it in the coments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return an integer to Matlab you can follow the instructions of the link you posted but modifying it a bit so integers are returned.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray * plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray * prhs[])
{
    // Create a 1-by-1 real integer. 
    // Integer classes are mxINT32_CLASS, mxINT16_CLASS, mxINT8_CLASS
    // depending on what you want.
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxINT16_CLASS, mxREAL);


    // fill in plhs[0] to contain the same as whatever you want 
    // remember that you may want to change your variabel class here depending on your above flag to *short int* or something else.
    int* data = (int*) mxGetData(plhs[0]); 
    // This asigns data the same memory address as plhs[0]. the return value

    data[0]=_tmain(0,0,0); //or data[0]=anyFunctionThatReturnsInt();
    return;

}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It did help, but my problem was half solved: no value was returned in _tmain() so now it works perfectly.