# How to output vector of integers in matlab mex file?

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, mex

I have a c++ code, which generates some sequence of integers. I need to write a mex file for matlab, which will give me the output.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>


void
mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
double *Input;
mxArray *mxInput,*mxOutput;
//associate inputs
mxInput = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]); 
Input=mxGetPr(mxInput);

// number of Steps
int NumOfSteps = (int) Input[0];
// collect diffs    
std::vector <int> result_vector;

// Initialize random generator
std::random_device rnd_device;
std::mt19937_64 rg(rnd_device());
std::normal_distribution<double> Xi(0,1);

// iterate

for (int iStep=0; iStep<NumOfSteps;iStep++) 
{
    if ((Xi(rg)-Xi(rg)) >= 0.5)
    {
       result_vector.push_back(iStep);
    }
}
// Here i should copy result_vector to output

}
```

I have an idea how to do it via cycle, coping results element-wise, but i hope there should be a better solution.

**Could You give me some advice how to have `result_vector` as output in my mex file?**

## Update:

I found the following solution:

```
int vecN = result_vector.size();
mxOutput = plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,vecN, mxREAL);    
Output=mxGetPr(mxOutput);
std::copy(result_vector.begin(),result_vector.end(),Output);
```

I am really bad in c++ is it correct way?

Comment: This but with other values? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783441/return-values-from-a-c-mex-file-to-matlab/31783968#31783968

Comment: May be I am dummy, the problem is not to output 1 value, but the whole vector

Comment: Why not something like memcpy()?

Comment: I've updated question, it seems I found something similar to Your suggestion.